# Is it ok for a thesis chapter to start with a figure?

Tags: thesis, books, graphics

Slightly different to the question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/155242/should-the-introduction-of-a-thesis-have-figures-pictures) which asks is it ok to put a figure in the introduction of a thesis, is it ok to start a thesis chapter with an illustration like a figure or table?

An even better answer might be give the pros and cons. An advantage I can think of is that it is nice to look at when a reader has to read through many pages of a thesis and if it also gives a summary of the whole chapter. A disadvantage I can think of is that it distracts from the chapter introductory text and might not look professional.

Comment: I think it is good practice to place a figure always after it's first reference in the text. So first have a verbal description, and then place the figure. If you are working with latex this might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641343/figure-placement-after-first-time-referenced-in-text

Answer (score 2):

If I saw a chapter starting with a figure, I would be slightly irritated at the writer for not making it clear whether I am supposed to look at the figure first or the text.

If you want to give the reader a break from endless text, just put one or two sentences first, explaining what the figure is or introducing the chapter, and then put the figure.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Also in reponse to @BerndGit's comment, I've decided to leave the figure at the bottom of the page with a caption and text before it referencing it.